# How to pass part of URL to ProxyPass in Apache

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, apache2.2

I'm hitting the URL http://example.com/ws/abc. Now I need to proxy a server with URL https://server.com/abc.

I have tried 2 below methods to proxy. But its not working.

1. `RewriteRule ^/ws/(.*) "https://server.com/$1" [P]`
2. `ProxyPassMatch ^/ws/(.*)  https://server.com/$1`

What is the possible issue?
I can't seem to get just the `abc` from the URL. I get `/ws/abc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RewriteRule and ProxyPassMatch you are using match exactly the same so only the RewriteRule is being interpreted, I suggest you take a more simple approach just with proxypass directives. If I understood correctly what you are trying to proxy it would be like:

```
ProxyPass /ws/ https://server.com/
ProxyPass /abc/ https://server.com/
```

First will match everything after /ws/ and append it to https://server.com/, second will match everything after /abc/ and append it to https://server.com/